# AngularJS: Calling custom directives from within a custom directive doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a [plunker here that demostrates it](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvBUBR).

I can create two directives. In this case one is named zMonthSelect, and the other is named zTest that references zMonthSelect.  Angular doesn't seem to like if they're nested. Why is that? What can I do to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('zMonthSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 1000,
        scope: {
            month: '=month'
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="month">' +
            '<option value="1">Jan</option>' +
            '<option value="2">Feb</option>' +
            '<option value="3">Mar</option>' +
            '<option value="4">Apr</option>' +
            '<option value="5">May</option>' +
            '<option value="6">Jun</option>' +
            '<option value="7">Jul</option>' +
            '<option value="8">Aug</option>' +
            '<option value="9">Sep</option>' +
            '<option value="10">Oct</option>' +
            '<option value="11">Nov</option>' +
            '<option value="12">Dec</option>' +
            '</select>',
        controller: function($scope) {
        }
    };
});


app.directive('zTest', function(){ 
  return { 
    restrict: 'E',
    priority: 1,
    scope: {},
    template: 'Test: <z-month-list month="1"></z-month-list>',
    controller: function($scope) {
    }
  };
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  zTest: <z-test></z-test><br/>
  zMonthSelect: <z-month-select></z-month-select><br/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mismatch in your directive name. In the `zTest` directive you're trying to use `<z-month-list>`, but your directive is named `zMonthSelect`. Just change your `zTest` directive to us `<z-month-select>`. See http://plnkr.co/edit/x2i8lv?p=preview

Or you can rename your inner directive to `zMonthList`. See http://plnkr.co/edit/aQlSqK?p=preview

Comment: Oh goddammit. That's what I get for coding after midnight. What's WORSE than that. Is I made that to demostrate something I was seeing in another project, and my issue there was I didn't have my .js files in the proper folder to be included in my bundling. Crap crap crap, I feel retarded.

Comment: :) No worries. It happens to the best of us.